# Find string in a List, if match, string = List name

Tags: c#, list, linq, unity-game-engine

So my gameobject string name contain an ID(first variable) in the List, since the List is a custom class with two variable. I want to switch the name gameobject name to the second
variable after comparing the first variable and returning True.

```
 if (gameData_List.showing_my_loading_list.Any(s => anchor.name.Contains(s.guid.ToString())))
                {
                    Debug.Log("Found)
                }
```

The result show 4 found, but what I'm trying to do is after knowing that is true, change the anchor.name to s.SecondVarible.Tostring();
However, after I set the condition in the if,
I no longer have access to the (s) in the Debug.Log area.

Comment: So is it like... `found result 1` -> `set anchor.name` -> `found result 2` -> `set anchor name` -> ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it myself, thanks

```
 var temp = gameData_List.showing_my_loading_list.Find(x => anchor.name.Contains(x.guid.ToString()));
                if (temp != null)
                {
                    anchor.name = temp.readable_guid;
                    Debug.Log("Changing Name");
                }
```

Comment: please remember to format Your code when giving answers ctrl+k and manual spacing at time, we all suffer and have to to make everything nice :) please

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to split it into lines you could probably do something like

```
anchor.name = gameData_List.showing_my_loading_list.FirstOrDefault(s => anchor.name.Contains(s.guid.ToString()))?.readable_guid ?? anchor.name;
```

So this does

- `FirstOrDefault`: Try to find an element `s` where the condition is matched or return `default` (= `null` for classes)
- `?.`: If it is **not** `null` use the `readable_guid`, otherwise return `null` again
- `??`: If the before is `null` use `anchor.name` (the old one) as fallback => change nothing

Of course this loses the ability to do more things when you found a valid element like your logging etc.

---

Alternatively, why not simply stick to a normal loop ;)

```
foreach(var s in gameData_List.showing_my_loading_list)
{
    if(anchor.name.Contains(s.guid.ToString())
    {
        anchor.name = s.readable_guid;
        Debug.Log("Changing Name");
        break;
    }
}
```

or with Linq again

```
foreach (var s in gameData_List.showing_my_loading_list.Where(s => anchor.name.Contains(s.guid.ToString())))
{
    anchor.name = s.readable_guid;
    Debug.Log("Changing Name");
    break;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, the reason not to do a loop is that the code is already in for each loop. my bad for not telling

Comment: @aronkan that doesn't really matter ... if you need to loop you need to loop ;) Linq does nothing else but iterate over your elements until finding a match ... a bit different of course but still you will iterate the same. Loops within loops are not bad per sé .. always depends what you need and do ;)

Answer (score -2):

gameData_List.showing_my_loading_list.filter(s => anchor.name.Contains(s.guid.ToString())).each(() => {
Debug.Log("Found)

})

Comment: `.filter` doesn't exist and how does this do what OP was trying .. it just logs `Found` .. OP already is exactly at that point. OP rather wants to later on reuse a value of the found element so either way you need to store/return that somehow

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).